# Word to mean 'seek through, one element at a time'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming

I'm looking for a word to describe the process that a computer program performs when

**searching through a dataset bit by bit**.

I had believed the word *parse* ('to parse through the data') was correct. However, it seems that the word *parse* actually means 'to split into pieces'.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of *trawl*, *seek*, *step through* etc. I just wonder if there is a more elegant word/phrase that I could use.

Comment: Perhaps, this could have been asked on SO/ programmersSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Iterate* is the word that's generally used for this, I believe:

> The program iterates through the collection, searching for every occurrence of the target value.

Comment: "iterate" is a great synonym for "step through", but doesn't necessarily match "seek" (as you can iterate for purposes other than search). Still I do think it's what the OP is looking for, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered it yourself with "trawl".

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trawl
"fish with a trawl net or seine, search thoroughly."

A possible problem is that some people confuse it with "troll".

You could use trudge, even if it doesn't literally mean that. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/trudge
"to walk laboriously or wearily along or over"

I often use sed to trudge through manifest files looking for old TV recordings.

Answer (score -1):

As a coder, I would call that a "for each" operation. Ex: "For Each item in this dataset, determine if it's what I want."

I don't know if 'for each' (or 'foreach') is a verb or not, though. "I foreached through the data" sounds awkward. And, per the answer above, using a 'for each' is a method of iteration.

Comment: No, I've never heard `for-each` / `for` / `while` / `do-while` or any other loop construct used verb. Although you could say *do X while Y*, that's not derived from the programming construct; in fact it's obviously the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

***bitScan*** has been used to mean bit-wise scanning of a byte/word.

However,

1. It is not a recognized generic term though it is easy to understand in context.
2. Some standard functions named *bitScan*<sup>1,2</sup> already exist. That should be an issue in the OP's context.

<sup>1</sup>ORACLE IA-32 Assembly Language
**[Bit Scan Forward (bsf)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-3773/instructionset-89/index.html)** scans the bits, starting at bit 0, in the doubleword operand or the second word. If the bits are all zero, ZF is cleared. Otherwise, ZF is set and the bit index of the first set bit, found while scanning in the forward direction, is loaded into the destination register.

<sup>2</sup>http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BitScan